# I want to do video streaming without buffering more than 1GB

Tags: javascript

I write my code for video streaming without buffering. It's working fine within 20 minutes videos. I tried more than 1GB video but unfortunately it's not working.I placed below my code.

```js
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

canvas.onclick = function (e) {
    var vl = vid.duration,
        w = canvas.width,
        x = e.clientX - 5;

    vid.currentTime = x / w * vl;
}

loop();

function loop() {

    var b = vid.buffered,
        i = b.length,
        w = canvas.width,
        h = canvas.height,
        vl = vid.duration,
        x1, x2;

    ctx.fillStyle = '#000';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
    ctx.fillStyle = '#d00';

    while (i--) {
        x1 = b.start(i) / vl * w;
        x2 = b.end(i) / vl * w;
        ctx.fillRect(x1, 0, x2 - x1, h);
    }
    ctx.fillStyle = '#fff';

    x1 = vid.currentTime / vl * w;
    ctx.textBaseline = 'top';
    ctx.textAlign = 'left';

    ctx.fillText(vid.currentTime.toFixed(1), 4, 4);

    ctx.textAlign = 'right';
    ctx.fillText(vl.toFixed(1), w - 4, 4);

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x1, h * 0.5, 7, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.fill();

    setTimeout(loop, 29);
}
play.addEventListener('click', function () {
    vid.play()
}, false);
pause.addEventListener('click', function () {
    vid.pause()
}, false);
```

This code is working within 20 minutes video only. I want to know how to do code for more than 1GB video. Please help me with code and example.

Comment: `I tried more than 1GB video but unfortunately it's not working` - any console errors to help with this mystery? Here's the thing, browsers don't care about the size of the stream- the problem is more likely that the bigger file is in an unsupported format

Comment: There is nothing about video streaming in this code block, just some text and a circle drawn on a canvas.

Comment: Thanks kaiido for your reply please give some example for this one.

Comment: There is no console errors it's working for 20 minutes video, for 1 gb video   its playing but if i click in middle or like that means it stopped so i need a solution.